# Rails Mongoid includes doesn't load child models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4, include, mongoid

I don't know exactly should it works how i expect or not, but i think that this:

```
  def show
    render json: Book.includes(:genres).find(params[:id])
  end
```

Should include genres in book model.

```
class Book
  include Mongoid::Document
  ...

  has_and_belongs_to_many :genres
end

class Genre
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :name, type: String
end
```

But on client in contains only list of genre ids.

```
genre_ids: Array[1]
  0: Object
  $oid: "53532d3b616c6439c1070000"
```

I also tried another model Author with book:

```
class Author
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :name, type: String

  has_many :books, inverse_of: :author
end

# in controller action

render json: Book.includes(:author).find(params[:id])

# returns =>
#    {"book":{"_id":{"$oid":"53532d3b616c6439c1140000"},"annotation":null,"author_id":{"$oid":"53532d3b616c6439c1000000"},"author_name":"Сомерсет Моэм","co_author_ids":[],"created_at":"2014-04-20T02:13:16.057Z","date":"1947","genre_ids":[{"$oid":"53532d3b616c6439c1070000"}],"html_path":"/Users/alder/Projects/pro_book_reader/rails-api/storage/GoCUMSZP/_.html","image_url":"GoCUMSZP.jpg","name":"Театр","toc_path":null,"token":"h9beplTN"}}
```

Same thing, it returns only `$oid` (`author_name` is a book model property)

So, could i load all genres models with book model, without extra queries?

Rails `4.1`, mongoid `4.0.0.beta1`

Also i don't have association in Genre model, because it will save all book ids in genre model.

**UPDATED**

Identity Map has been removed from mongoid 4. There is new `preload_models` option, but it's not load genres too when true.

**PS**

It works with `render json: {book: book, genres: book.genres}`, so maybe thats fine until `includes` will be fixed.

**PS2**

I think perhaps this `includes` is not what i'm thinking of. I mean maybe it's just helps to avoid extra queries after you appeal to relational model(s). And it doesn't create array from all childs, or add `author` object to author field (that what any expect, not useless `ID`).

Comment: Perhaps i should use jbuilder for this task.

Comment: `But on client in contains only list of genre ids.` ? Can you share the code of view where you are trying to display the associated genres of a book.

Comment: I just get json response with angularjs. I don't think the frontend code is metter. Of course, i can send an array with genres in json, or get it from frontend with another query. I want that genres will be already included in json. Otherwise, what this `includes(:genres)` does? Perhaps there are eager option for this case, or something.

Comment: I need sql analog for join in basis of mongodb.

Comment: There is an open bug in mongoid that might be useful https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/issues/2041

Comment: Yes, was reopened exactly when identity map was removed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**To display `genres` for each of all available `books`:**

```
def show 
  books = Book.all 
  render json: books, include: :genres 
end
```

**To display `genres` for a particular `book`:**

```
def show 
  book = Book.find(params[:id]) 
  render json: book, include: :genres 
end
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to enable the identity map in mongoid.yml for eager loading to work

```
identity_map_enabled: true
```

in options.

Comment: identity map was removed in version 4.

Answer (score 0):

Identity Map has been `removed from mongoid master (mongoid4)`. You can check with the issue opened for further details, https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/issues/3406.

Also mongoid 4 change log shows in `Major Changes (Backward Incompatible)` as identity map is removed. https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/blob/006063727efe08c7fc5f5c93ef60be23327af422/CHANGELOG.md.

As they suggested, Eager load will work without identity map now.

Comment: I know, but it doesn't